# Laravel 5.6 custom registration using auth class

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys i am new to laravel and i am trying to make a login system for `lecturer`and `admin` where the admin can register and edit the users details. I am aware that Laravel has an in-built auth system but it does not have the the function to edit the user details. There are two options that i thought that might work

1. Use the existing auth system for register/login while adding a new controller and view to edit the users details.
2. create a new register/login system from scratch with a new migration table and implement the edit functions. But my concern is if i create from scratch how to i use the Auth() class to handle the access control?

Anyone able to clarify for me which option works??

Comment: Editing users and authenticating them have nothing to do with each other. Take what's there and build on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you to use laravel Auth Class and then use some ACL package like laravel-permission
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

to handle you user as admin,guest and so more
you can create multi level users with different permissions and roles

Answer (score 0):

Definitely option one

It's always good to use Laravels built-in user scaffolding 
Most of the authentication and authorization for your application will already be handled

Why reinvent the wheel? Option 1 it is.

Comment: hi,mr. raj
i recommend you to study this article to understand what i mean ,it's not about creating wheel it's about using new things to improve our ability

https://laravel-news.com/two-best-roles-permissions-packages